# Reference found where even-sized list expected

Tags: perl

I am writing this code in perl where i create a unique key and then assign a value to it.

```
  sub populate {
      my $file = shift;
      my %HoH = shift;

      open(INFILE,$file);
      .
      .
      .  
      $final_name = $prepend.$five;
      $HoH{$final_name} = $seven;
 }
```

Now i am passing in two parameters to a subroutine which id like

```
&populate(\%abc,$file_1);
&populate(\%xyz,$file_2);
```

Why does it give me an error like this:

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected
```

Comment: Whatever documentation you're reading that tells you to use the two-argument form of "open" is out of date.  Use the three-argument form: `open my $INFILE, '<', $file`.  (And check for errors.)

Comment: but $file contains the address of the location of the file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  `$file` should contain the *name* of the file.  The calls `open(INFILE, $file)` and `open my $INFILE, '<', $file` are nearly equivalent, but the latter is better.  `perldoc -f open` for more information.  (And you're missing a '$' in your source; `my file = shift;` should be `my $file = shift;`.)

Comment: oh that was a typo.In the actual code i had typed that. So it prints the stuff for the 1st file but not for the 2nd file.

Comment: There is no `print` statement in your code. How can it possibly print anything?

Comment: This is why you should copy-and-paste your code, not retype it.

Comment: @TLP: i shall keep that in mind.And regarding the print , what i meant was store the values in the hash HoH.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because your hash is assigned to a reference, and not a hash (even-sized list). You need to do:

```
my $hashref = shift;

...

$hashref->{$final_name} = $seven;
```

ETA: You should call subroutines without `&`, e.g. `populate(...)`, unless you specifically want to override the prototype of the sub. If you don't know what a prototype is, just don't use `&`.

ETA2: You really should use a lexical filehandle and three-argument open. Consider this scenario:

```
open INFILE, $file;
some_sub();
$args = <INFILE>;  # <--- Now reading from a closed filehandle

sub some_sub {
    open INFILE, $some_file;
    random code...
    close INFILE;
}
```

Comment: thanks.So have i passed in the hash to the subroutine properly &populate(\%abc,$file_1)

Comment: Well, no, since you are assigning `\%abc` to the file, and `$file_1` to the hash.

Comment: it gives me an error saying Use of uninitialized value in open.I am opening like this open(<INFILE>,$file)

Comment: where i assume that the value of file_1 will be used by $file for the 1st time and then the value of file_2 will be used by $file for the 2nd  time.

Comment: Yes, shift takes the first value in a list. So with `populate(\%abc, $file_1)`, the first `shift` is the hash, the second the file.

Comment: :now i get it.I think what mistake i am making is including the opening of the file in the subroutine.But then is that not fine? I am passing the value of the $file n then operating on it.

Comment: populate(\%synt,$syn_file);

sub populate
{
  my $HoH = shift;
  my $file = shift;
  open(INFILE,$file);
  $flag = 0;
    while (<INFILE>)
This is what i am doing and it gives me an error.

Comment: I have answered your question. If you have a new question, post a new question. Don't keep asking follow-ups in the comments.

Comment: When i try to print the variables $_0,$_1 and so on.....i find them empty.Nothing is stored in them.

Comment: $_[0], $_[1] are the variables you're looking for.  They are the first two elements of the @_ array.