# Perl: Not enough arguments for function

Tags: perl

I'm quite a newcomer to Perl and currently trying to understand mentioned error message.

I've got this piece of code (still mostly for testing pourposes)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %info = (autor => "Karryanna", jazyk => "cs");

vec([%info]);

sub vec
{
  my ($hashref) = @_;
  print $hashref->autor . "\n";
}
```

When I try to run it, it gives this error message

```
Not enough arguments for vec at test.pl line 8, near "])"
```

When I tried to google it, I found [this site](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=293902) which just made me think that preceding the subroutine call with an ampersand is enough. I tried it and it really did help.

However, when I later on ran into another problem, googling took me to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985643/reference-found-where-even-sized-list-expected). The point is that the answer states

> You should call subroutines without &, e.g. populate(...), unless you specifically want to override the prototype of the sub. If you don't know what a prototype is, just don't use &.

I've got absolutely no idea what a prototype in Perl context is.
So - what's the reality like? Should I just use & or is there any other, perhaps more "clean", solution?

Thanks!

(By the way, if I may ask a little bit OT question -- Should I really define subroutine after calling it? It seems really unnatural to me, however, I've already discovered that reverting the order makes the compiler complain)

Comment: `vec` is a built-in function.

Comment: Besides what aschepler just said about `vec()` being a built-in function (which conflicts with your sub's name), you should probably pass your hash ref like this: `vec(\%info)`, otherwise you will have problems with more complex hash structures.

Comment: I probably agree that calling vec(\%info) would be better in this case. However, it I wanted to edit the content inside the subroutine without affecting the variable outside of the subroutine, I'd have to call it like I do it now, is it correct?

Comment: @Karryanna You can still make copies of parts of the hash without altering the original. E.g. `my $foo = $href->{'foo'}; $foo =~ s/foo/bar/g;` Just make sure not to copy references, since they will lead to the same memory location.`

Comment: @TLP OK, I probably see it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vec` is a perl built-in function, you are getting a name collision (`perldoc -f vec`).  Call your subroutine something else.

You probably want to call it like this:

```
mysub(\%info)
```

In Perl you can call a subroutine either before or after you declare it.  The only restrictions on that are when using prototypes, which you probably don't want to do.   What errors do you get when you reverse the order ("makes the compiler complain" doesn't help much)?  It might be because of the name collision.

Comment: If it really has to be the name `vec`, one could `use subs qw/vec/` to override the builtin for the current package..

Comment: Argh, this is a stupid mistake. The error was... "Ambigous call resolved as CORE::vec(), qualify as such or use &". It makes perfect sence now. Well, hopefully this is gonna get better with days and years of experience. Anyway, thanks for your help.