# Not enough arguments when redefining a subroutine

Tags: perl, arguments, subroutine

When I redefine my own subroutine (and not a Perl built-in function), as below :

```
perl -ce 'sub a($$$){} sub b {a(@_)}'
```

I get this error :

> Not enough arguments for main::a at -e line 1, near "@_)"

I'm wondering why.

Edit :

The word "redefine" is maybe not well chosen. But in my case (and I probably should have explained what I was trying to do originally), I want to redefine (and here "redefine" makes sense) the Test::More::is function by printing first Date and Time before the test result.

Here's what I've done :

```
Test::More.pm :

sub is ($$;$) {
    my $tb = Test::More->builder;

    return $tb->is_eq(@_);
}


MyModule.pm :

sub is ($$;$) {
   my $t    = gmtime(time);
   my $date = $t->ymd('/').' '.$t->hms.' ';

   print($date);
   Test::More::is(@_);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl: Not enough arguments for function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043414/perl-not-enough-arguments-for-function)

Comment: The issue with this question is that a Perl built-in function is redefined. Here I redefine my own function.

Comment: `&Test::More::is( @_ )` will work here, with a comment to say why. Your prototype is forcing `@_` to be evaluated in scalar context, so it passes one parameter which is the *number of elements* in `@_`. You want the prototype to be ignored so that you can pass the *contents* of `@_`, which is what a call with `&` does.

Comment: Thank you @Borodin , indeed with `&Test::More::is( @_ )` it works well!

Comment: Maybe you should write an answer so that I validate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Perl, prototypes don't validate arguments so much as alter parsing rules. `$$;$` means the sub expects the caller to match `is(EXPR, EXPR)` or `is(EXPR, EXPR, EXPR)`.

In this case, bypassing the prototype is ideal.

```
sub is($$;$) {
   print gmtime->strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S ");
   return &Test::More::is(@_);
}
```

Since you don't care if `Test::More::is` modifies yours `@_`, the following is a simple optimization:

```
sub is($$;$) {
   print gmtime->strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S ");
   return &Test::More::is;
}
```

If `Test::More::is` uses `caller`, you'll find the following useful:

```
sub is($$;$) {
   print gmtime->strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S ");
   goto &Test::More::is;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The prototype that you have given your subroutine (copied from `Test::More::is`) says that your subroutine requires two mandatory parameters and one optional one. Passing in a single array will not satisfy that prototype - it is seen as a single parameter which will be evaluated in scalar context.

The fix is to retrieve the two (or three) parameters passed to your subroutine and to pass them, individually, to `Test::More::is`.

```
sub is ($$;$) {
   my ($got, $expected, $test_name) = @_;

   my $t    = gmtime(time);
   my $date = $t->ymd('/').' '.$t->hms.' ';

   print($date);
   Test::More::is($got, $expected, $test_name);
}
```

The problem has nothing to do with your use of a prototype or the fact that you are redefining a subroutine (which, strictly, you aren't as the two subroutines are in different packages) but it's  because `Test::More::is()` has a prototype.

Comment: @ikegami: I'm a little wary of recommending a solution that overrides a safety feature (no matter how ill-advised that safety feature is).

Comment: Why, because the prototype might change? Your code will still break then.

Comment: @ikegami: I just think it's a bad habit to get into. But I'm happy to admit that's probably a personal foible that's unhelpful here :-)

Answer (score 5):

You are not redefining anything here.

You've set a [*prototype*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) for your sub `a` by saying `sub a($$$)`. The dollar signs in the function definition tell Perl that this sub has exactly three scalar parameters. When you call it with `a(@_)`, Perl doesn't know how many elements will be in that list, thus it doesn't know how many arguments the call will have, and fails at compile time.

**Don't mess with prototypes**. You probably don't need them.

Instead, if you know your sub will need three arguments, explicitly grab them where you call it.

```
sub a($$$) {
    ...
} 

sub b {
    my ($one, $two, $three) = @_; 
    a($one, $two, $three);
}
```

Or better, don't use the prototype at all.

---

Also, `a` and `b` are terrible names. Don't use them.

Comment: I don't think the issue is that *"Perl doesn't know how many elements the call will have"* but instead that the call is passing only one parameter when three are required. A call like `a(@_, @_, @_)` would work fine. Each parameter is evaluated in scalar context and will be equal to the number of elements in `@_`.